# Get-eventlog - get the last 100 errors in the output with a structure of an ip address error in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to limit the last 100 errors that have the same structure as an ip address( example {1,3} . \ D {1,3} . \ D {1,3} . \ D {1, 3 }) using get-eventlog. I get the output printed out which shows the last 100 events on the computer, but how can i structure the output and how do i get the error messages from eventlog in powershell?

```
Get-Eventlog -Newest 100 -LogName "Application"
```

Comment: What have you tried to do to accomplish your goals, and what errors are you getting?

Comment: I am trying to get the last 100 errors from using the eventlog in powershell. The errors are not being listed out, i only get listed out the last 100 events

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameter `-EntryType` to specify the type of log entries, that you are interested in.

```
Get-Eventlog -Newest 100 -LogName "Application" -EntryType Error
```

Comment: how do you get the details, there message's are truncated

Comment: They only appear truncated in table view in your console. Pipe the command to `Format-List`. You will see the untruncated values there.